# Repeating for loop within a function Python 3

Tags: python, for-loop, random, repeat

I have been working on this problem for an Intro to Programming with Python class for days now. The goal is to create a program that generates random movie titles from a list of user-inputed words. The output should look something like this:

```
Please enter a list of words: ["Space", "Show", "Adventure", "Story", 
"Love", "Wild", "Life"]

Please enter a number of movies you'd like to generate: 3
```

Output:

> Welcome to Randoplex! Currently playing movies are:
>
> Adventure Life Space
>
> Show Love Story
>
> Wild Space Life

I have been able to generate random titles, but cannot find anyway to generate different titles based on the user-inputed number. This is the closest I have gotten:

```
import random

def random_movies(word_list = eval(input("Please enter a list of words:"))):

    for word in word_list:
        titles = ' '.join(random.choice(word_list) for i in range(3))
    return titles

def repeat():

  titles = random_movies()
  movie_num = eval(input("Please enter the number of movies you'd like to  generate:"))

 for i in range(movie_num):
    random_movies()
    print(titles)

titles1 = repeat()
print("Welcome to Randoplex! Currently playing movies are:")
print()
print(titles1)
```

This allows me to print the same randomized title for the value `movie_num` that the user enters. But, I just cannot figure out how to create multiple different randomized movie titles. I have tried using the `range()` function in many different ways, and have looked all over the internet for advice. I truly don't know what else to try at this point, any help would be greatly appreciated. It is important to mention that my class is very elementary, we haven't been introduced to "while" loops yet and I don't think I am allowed to use them because of that. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Normally using `eval()` is not generally a good idea as if the input is wrong, you will get an `error`, it is better practice to have the user input the words separated by `spaces` and `split` it, or to just do a `for-loop` and `append` to a list until an end character...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you're looking for?

```
import random

def random_movies(word_list):
    for word in word_list:
        titles = ' '.join(random.choice(word_list.split()) for i in range(3))
        return titles

word_list = input("Please enter a list of words:")
movie_num = int(input("Please enter the number of movies you'd like to  generate:"))

print("Welcome to Randoplex! Currently playing movies are:")

for i in range(movie_num):
    print(random_movies(word_list))
```

Comment: You forgot the parentheses at the `print` function in your for loop :)

Comment: @MushroomMauLa he is on python 2

Comment: @bulbus but he uses python 3 syntax before

Comment: @ bulbus,  Yep.  I'd changed raw_input back to input for 2 ->3 for the OP but forgot to do print

Comment: Last print statement now has parentheses for 3.

Comment: This does exactly what I needed! Thanks for your comment, I had been stuck on this for days.

Answer (score 0):

Your functions are working correctly however in your for loop where you print the movie titles you forgot to reassign your variable to the newly generated movie title. Your different titles are generated but you print only the first one.

```
import random

def random_movie(word_list = eval(input("Please enter a list of words:"))):
    for word in word_list:
        title = ' '.join(random.choice(word_list) for i in range(3))
        return title

def repeat():
    movie_num = eval(input("Please enter the number of movies you'd like to  generate:"))
    for i in range(movie_num):
        title = random_movie()
        print(title)

print("Welcome to Randoplex! Currently playing movies are: ")
print()
repeat()
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted

Answer (score -1):

another way to achieve similar result.

```
import itertools
import random
noofmovies = 3
movies =  ["Space", "Show", "Adventure", "Story", "Love", "Wild", "Life"]
newmovies = []
def random_movie(movies):

    for r in range(2,len(movies)):
        for elem in itertools.combinations(movies, r):
            newmovies.append(" ".join(elem))


def repeat():
    random.shuffle(newmovies)
    for elem in newmovies[0:noofmovies]:
        print (elem)


print("Welcome to Randoplex! Currently playing movies are: ")
random_movie(movies)
repeat()
```

output:

```
Show Adventure Story Wild Life
Story Wild Life
Show Adventure Story Love Wild Life
```

In case you want only 3 movie names to be joined always, remove for r in range(2,len(movies)): loop and hardcode r to 3

Comment: Why would you remove the working interactive inputs and hard-code them. If anything this looks like a step back...